# проигрывание аудио через url

Tags: ios, swift, url, iphone, аудио

Я использую AVAudioPlayer для проигрывания аудио, но вылетает ошибка.

Вот мой код:

```
var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer!
var soundChange = true

  @IBAction func play(_ sender: Any) {


    let url = NSURL(string: "/upload/iblock/f64/f64aa1d14b7fb2fe5de5f68922ee506f.mp3")! as URL

    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)



        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateAudioProgressView), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        progressView.setProgress(Float(audioPlayer.currentTime/audioPlayer.duration), animated: false)

    } catch {
        print("An error occurred while trying to extract audio file")
    }
```

Тут выводит ошибку: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
if !audioPlayer.isPlaying && soundChange == true{
        playChange.setImage(UIImage(named:"Pause.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        soundChange = false
        audioPlayer.play()    
    } else {
        playChange.setImage(UIImage(named:"Play.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        soundChange = true
        audioPlayer.pause()
    }
}
```

Comment: а можно настоящий url, чтоб можно было к себе код скопировать, запустить и посмотреть

Comment: @Max Mikheyenko https://stmegi.com/upload/iblock/f64/f64aa1d14b7fb2fe5de5f68922ee506f.mp3

Comment: а что за ошибка?

Comment: @Max Mikheyenko fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value но ссылка не оптиональная в условии if !audioPlayer.isPlaying

Comment: Я бы не спешил уверять, что audioPlayer не optional, так как он implicity unwrapped optional. У вас падает в catch? Тогда audioPlayer у Вас nil.

Comment: @Max Mikheyenko в catch попадает, как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вкратце, то AVAudioPlayer не играет url'ы, либо локальные файлы, либо про данные в NSData формате. Что вам надо сделать: сначала взять файл и сконвертировать в Data, и уже потом играть

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let url = URL(string: "https://stmegi.com/upload/iblock/f64/f64aa1d14b7fb2fe5de5f68922ee506f.mp3")

        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
            self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: data)
            audioPlayer.play()
        } catch let error as NSError{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо тебе, работает